# Constraint spacing UILabel in For Loop

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

I have a small problem and hope someone can help me solve it ... I searched the net and made some attempts, but I could not solve my problem.

I created a FOR loop that plays a specified number of labels obtained through an array, as you can see from the code that I posted below ...

Now my problem is how to insert constraint programmatically. I need that between a label and the other (horizontal) there is a specific space.

Example:

if I label 4 I would like these would take around the horizontal space is in the iPhone display SE both iPhone 7 Plus ..

So my question is how do I set a specific space between each label and pass in the FOR loop?

```
CGFloat padding = 0;

NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"INFO UNIVERSITARIE",@"INFO GENERALI", @"TROVA SEDI", nil];

for (NSInteger i = 0;  i < array.count; i ++) {

    NSString *valueText = [array objectAtIndex:i];

    UILabel *label  = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.frame = CGRectMake(padding *i, 0, 50, 30);
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", valueText];
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    label.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:12];
    [label sizeToFit];

    [_baseView addSubview:label];

    padding = label.frame.size.width;

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
}
```

Comment: What is "ripercuoterlo"?

Comment: the translator did wrong .. sorry  ripercuoterlo = pass

Comment: Can we do the layout with simple arithmetic? The automatic feature is much more complex to code, but will work through things like rotation

Comment: I wanted to use the constraint to fit perfectly every label of For Loop on every device

Comment: We can use static frames to fit perfectly based on super view width on any device. The constraint system makes this dynamic for run time changes like device rotations and moving the labels in response to changes in related views. It comes at a cost, though: it is tougher to code and understand.

Comment: Why all this? It is so much complicated to use NSConstraint autolayout live programming for the label in a for loop?

Comment: It more complex relative to simple arithmetic.  I'll try to outline a solution in a few mins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Researching this, I remembered that the `UIStackView` is our new friend, designed specifically for this problem.

```
    NSArray *array = @[ @"INFO UNIVERSITARIE",@"INFO GENERALI", @"TROVA SEDI" ];
    NSMutableArray *labels = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (NSString *string in array) {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] init];
        label.text = string;
        [labels addObject:label];
    }

    UIStackView *stackView = [[UIStackView alloc] initWithArrangedSubviews:labels];
    stackView.axis = UILayoutConstraintAxisHorizontal;
    stackView.spacing = 12.0;
    stackView.frame = self.view.bounds;
    [self.view addSubview:stackView];
```

Just learned about this myself, but I tried this code and it works nicely.